# Angular 2 how to work with ngModules along with Angular's modules

Tags: angular

I'm a bit confused when it comes to the new `@ngModules`, what to import where and whatnot.

What I have now is a main app module, a shared module and several feature modules (smaller modules which group functionality together).

I import all the feature modules into the shared module, and then I can pass around the shared module to other modules in my app.

Now the problem I'm facing, or just a general laziness concern, is that when I need to use common directives such as `*ngIf` or anything else in a feature module or any module for that matter, I have to import the Angular modules into every module in order to gain access to directives, http etc.

Now my question is, can you import the necessary modules such as the `CommonModule, FormsModule, HttpModule` into the top level module, in this case the main app module, and let every other module and its different directives, components etc. have access to them at all times without having to import them in every module? Like if you import them and then export them from the top level module or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to make each of your feature modules self-contained. Each of them can import the shared module, which would have any general-purpose components, services or pipes, and then any common angular modules like `CommonModule`, `FormsModule`, etc. The shared module shouldn't import any of your feature modules.

Your app module can import each feature module and the shared module.

Here's a basic example of the shared module file:

```
import { NgModule, CommonModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
   exports: [CommonModule, FormsModule]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: Ok, but does the feature modules gain access to the shared module if I import the shared and feature modules into the main app? Or do I have to import the shared module into every feature module as well? Because I were having difficulties with this because it could never find the shared module despite the path and name being correct when importing it.

Comment: Yes you will have to import the shared module into each feature module.

Comment: That's a drag.. urgh.

Comment: Ya sorry. It's annoying, but it also forces you to be explicit about your module dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to read the NgModule [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html), but specifically the [shared](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module) module.

Basically on your SharedModule, you can re export other modules:

```
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }        from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }         from '@angular/forms';
import { AwesomePipe }         from './awesome.pipe';
import { HighlightDirective }  from './highlight.directive';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ AwesomePipe, HighlightDirective ],
  exports:      [ AwesomePipe, HighlightDirective,
                  CommonModule, FormsModule ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Be exporting the `CommonModule` and the `FormsModule` you don't need to import them across your app, because by just importing the ShareModule you are also importing them.

> While reviewing our application, we noticed that many components requiring SharedModule directives also use `NgIf` and `NgFor` from CommonModule and bind to component properties with `[(ngModel)],` a directive in the `FormsModule`. Modules that declare these components would have to import `CommonModule`, `FormsModule` and `SharedModule`.
>
> We can reduce the repetition by having `SharedModule` re-export `CommonModule` and `FormsModule` so that importers of `SharedModule` get `CommonModule` and `FormsModule` for free.